# Does it make sense to look at data generated from a multivariate distribution as univariate data and try to estimate its "distribution?"

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose I have multivariate normal  $X_{n}\sim MVN(\underline{\mu},\Sigma)$ where $n$ is large (several thousands). However, the $\mu_i's$ and the elements of $\Sigma$ are such that almost every simulation from $X_n$ yields a set of numbers that look like some specific univariate distribution. Is it reasonable to estimate this distribution?

For example, using R, I generate 10000 numbers from exp(1/20)

mu<-rexp(10000,1/20)

Then, I use each of these numbers $mu_i$ as a mean for one of the components of a MVN. For simplicity, I assume the components are independent and that the variance components are $mu_i/100$

So, a single vector simulated from this MVN would be:

y<-numeric(10000)

for(i in 1:10000){
y[i]<-rnorm(1,mu[i],mu[i]/100)
}

Now I have a vector y that is one simulation from my MVN. What I am interested in is that when I look at the values in the y vector together (the 10000 components of the vector), they then resemble a univariate distribution.